# Does Tesseract in Sikuli support single word only?

Tags: java, tesseract, sikuli

I'm doing some research with Sikuli now.

I find that **findText()** can only match some continuous string.(It will find nothing if there is spaces between string).

For example,

screen.find("Quick Access") will throw Find Failed exception.

Why does this happen?

My Sikuli version is 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The OCR is terribly unreliable. The OCR can find spaces, not that it always does. The error could be in not finding the space, or it could be that any one of the other letters is not being recognized correctly. I find that I can use OCR on the exact same page 10 times and come up with 6 or 7 different results. If the text you are looking for is selectable, you can get it to the clipboard and evaluate it much more efficiently from there (as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362028/using-sikuli-to-verify-text/20374321#20374321)).

If you must use the OCR, sometimes first zooming in on your desired text can help increase accuracy. Also, you could also have it search for the 3 or 4 most likely variants of your target phrase.

You're getting the FindFailed because it is not finding your exact phrase. To review what the OCR *is* finding, you can use:

```
print text() #this will print all text found in your default region (usually the entire screen)
```

-or-

```
print myRegion.text() #to print all text in a previous defined region, myRegion.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract defines a minimum font size of 20 pixels. Typical text on screen is between 7 and 10 pixels high. Sikuli must zoom by a factor of two or three, otherwise the process will appear "very unreliable".